# Google public calendar link doesn't work (fullcalendar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to use the "fullcalendar" on my site to generate public cal.

So, I've generated an XML link:

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/funky-flava.com_gtuilvhr9dnft0ututonqg51b0%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic
```

And when I init it in the "event" section it's doesn't work...

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/funky-flava.com_gtuilvhr9dnft0ututonqg51b0%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic'
});
```

Ready link looks like this:

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/funky-flava.com_gtuilvhr9dnft0ututonqg51b0%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json-in-script&callback=jQuery18104237642253283411_1347107892685&start-min=2012-08-26T00%3A00%3A00Z&start-max=2012-10-07T00%3A00%3A00Z&singleevents=true&max-results=9999&_=1347107892732</pre></code>
```

Comment: I get a 403 Forbidden error when I try to access the google calendar. I don't think it is public. Also, do you have the `gcal.js` in your HTML?

Comment: First link works, the second works when I you change word "full" to "base". Yes, I have the gcal.js in my code.

Comment: Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/QKPFQ/. I used the exact same string as you - I get 403 forbidden!

Answer (score 5):

Google has deprecated their v2 api as of Nov. 17 see http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.ca/2014/06/calendar-gdata-api-google-calendar.html

This will affect all applications targetting the v2 API which fullcalendar does at this point.